# Whats this weird crease in my subsurface mod?

Tags: modifiers

So I'm following a youtube tutorial for some character modeling and there's this weird crease down my center face line when I have the subsurface mod on. I've tried smoothing the verts but then my shape is too deformed. I've also tried to create some more geometry to make the vertex less "pointy" looking.
Here's a pic:
[image]

Comment: It would help if we could see the mesh you've used to generate the object. But just for starters, check if you've got *Auto-smooth Normals* enabled.

Comment: At first sight, this  looks like flipped normals. .. Alt-N > recalculate, one way or another?

Comment: As in without the mod?

Comment: I did the alt-N and flipped them. But the crease remains

Comment: Fliipping them is pointless, you want to re-calculate them, as it looks like only half of the normals are flipped.  Re-calculating them will make them uniform across the surface.

Comment: I did shift+n and shift+ctrl+n and it didn't fix it.
I'll try and upload something using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
but it seems like it's quite slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was fooling around some more. In the subsurface mod, there's an option called merge. That seems to have fixed the crease issue. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

[image]1 year later...
If you have a mirror modifier, make sure it's above the subdivision surface modifier (at least in Blender 2.7).

Comment: Two years now lol. But what did it was enabling the merge option on my subsurface modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Note: my answers are for the old Blender 2.79. Not sure how to do it in new Blender 2.8.

Try removing doubles. Select all vertices in edit mode, press space bar, type : remove doubles and press enter.
 (I think it's now called "Merge By Distance" in Blender 2.8?).

Or select the edges-in-question and lower their Mean Crease (press shift+E, and type in -1 and enter).

If that doesn't work, can you upload your blend files?

Happy holidays!

Comment: I merged by distance and no verts were removed. I also used the crease tool as you suggested and that didn't seem to work either.